# SQL Checking Substring in a String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with column `mapping` which store record: `"IV=>0J,IV=>0Q,IV=>2,V=>0H,V=>0K,VI=>0R,VI=>1,"`

What is the sql to check whether or not a substring is in column mapping.
so, I would like this:

- if I have `"IV=>0J"` would return true, because `IV=>0J` is exact in string "mapping"
- if I have `"IV=>01"` would return false. And so on...

I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE charindex('IV=>0J',mapping)
```

But when I have `"IV=>0"`, it returns TRUE. But, it should return FALSE.

Thank You..

Comment: Why not use `WHERE mapping LIKE '%IV=>OJ%`?

Comment: @Philips charindex searches an expression for another expression and returns its starting position if found.

Comment: @Aleks: It doesn't work, because if '%IV=>O%' it's also true. But, i want it FALSE. I just want it will return TRUE when the substring exact match in main string.

Comment: This is a bad design. You are using a column to store what should be rows in a separate table. Short of using regular expressions to parse the string, with the obvious performance hit, you can't avoid false positives. You COULD search for `IV=>0,` but it's still bad relational design. LIKE or CHARINDEX can't take advantage of any indexes too, which means that your query will result in a full table scan

Comment: @Ocaso Protal: oppss. I'm sorry. Yeah.. its work.. thank you...

Comment: Start by not denormalising your data into a comma seperated list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
    mapping LIKE '%,IV=>0J,%'
    OR mapping LIKE '%,IV=>0J'
    OR mapping LIKE 'IV=>0J,%'
    OR mapping = 'IV=>0J'
```

But you should really  normalize the database - you are currently violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity), and therefore the 1NF. Your current difficulties in querying and the future difficulties with performance that you are about to encounter all stem from this root problem...

Answer (score 4):

You can search with commas included. Just also add one at beginning and end of `mapping`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE charindex(',IV=>0J,',',' + mapping + ',') <> 0
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ',' + mapping + ',' LIKE '%,IV=>OJ,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can search by including a comma in the string, this is a bad design for several reasons.

- You are unable to take advantage of indexing
- You force a full scan of the table, which will lead to bad performance AND excessive blocking.
- You have to make sure that there is always a leading or a trailing comma (depends on what you expect in your LIKE expression).
- You are no longer able to edit a single entry, you'll have to replace the entire string each time you want to change even a single mapping.
- You open yourself to a concurrency nightmare if more that one users try to update different mappings that just happen to be stored in the same column.
- Your table isn't even in 1st normal form any more, which is why you have such difficulties

You should normalize your `mapping` column, by extracting the data to a different mapping table, with at least the `From` and `To` columns you require. You can then add these columns to an index an convert your query using only a single index seek.

You can also add the ID values of your source table to the `Mappings` table and the index. This will allow you to convert the lookup for a source row to a join between the two tables that takes advantage of indexing

Answer (score 0):

charindex returns the position of the text, not Boolean.

to check if the text exists, compare to 0:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE charindex('IV=>0J',mapping) <> 0
```

Comment: Yes you're right. But, here I just assumed in my code if the records > 0 return TRUE, otherwise FALSE. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing something here, the **Charindex** function does not return TRUE or FALSE.
It returns the starting point of the substring inside master string, or if the substring is not present, then -1.
So you query should read,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE charindex('IV=>0J',mapping) > 0
```